Conway's Game of Life Verilog
I'm learning Verilog alone, one of the tools I'm using is the the site 'HDLBITS' which has a lot of exercises. I'm trying to write a script for Conway's Game of Life but the output is not as I expected. In the game I have a 16X16 toroidal grid and each clock cycle I need to update the grid status according to the previous state, each cell is updated by it's neighbors status:
0-1 neighbor: Cell becomes 0.
2 neighbors: Cell state does not change.
3 neighbors: Cell becomes 1.
4+ neighbors: Cell becomes 0.

The Script:
module top_module (
    input logic clk,
    input logic load,
    input logic [255:0] data,
    output logic [255:0] q
);

    logic [255:0] temp_q;
    
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
        if (load) begin
            q <= data; // Load initial state into q
        end else begin
            q <= temp_q; // Update q with computed values
        end
    end

    genvar i, j;
    generate
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) begin : row_index
            for (j = 0; j < 16; j = j + 1) begin : column_index
                check_cell game (
                    .clk(clk),
                    .load(load),
                    .cell_checked(data[i*16 + j]),
                    .neighbours({data[(((i-1)+16) % 16) * 16 + (((j-1)+16) % 16)],
                                 data[(((i-1)+16) % 16) * 16 + (j)],
                                 data[(((i-1)+16) % 16) * 16 + (((j+1) % 16))],
                                 data[(i * 16) + (((j-1)+16) % 16)],
                                 data[(i * 16) + (((j+1) % 16))],
                                 data[((((i+1) % 16)) * 16) + (((j-1)+16) % 16)],
                                 data[((((i+1) % 16)) * 16) + (j)],
                                 data[((((i+1) % 16)) * 16) + (((j+1) % 16))]
                                }), 
                    .qcell(temp_q[i*16 + j])
                );
            end
        end
    endgenerate

endmodule

module check_cell (
    input logic clk,
    input logic load,
    input logic cell_checked,
    input logic [7:0] neighbours, 
    output logic qcell
);

    logic [3:0] counter=0;

    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
     
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k = k + 1) begin
            if (neighbours[k] == 1)
                counter <= counter + 1;
        end
        if (counter == 2)
            qcell = cell_checked;
        else if (counter == 3)
            qcell = 1'b1;
        else
            qcell = 1'b0;
    end

endmodule

The output is that 'q' does not updates every clock cycle, for the firs q is equal to the input and then it shows all zeroes for two clock cycles, and than some cells turn into don't cares.
I tried also to write the condition to neighbors with 'if' but got a compile error

I dont have a test-bench, the 'HDLBITS' site have a test enviorment
